# Html5 video problems

Tags: css, html

I've been getting a problem with html in my presentation video:

The video keeps paralyzed, until its fully loaded, and then start to play.

In some browsers it works, others do not. Can someone help me to fix it?

HTML

```
<div class="videoContainer">
<video autoplay loop preload='auto'>
<source src="video/Rio_Energy_Apresentacao.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
Video não suportado.
</video>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.videoContainer
{
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.videoContainer video
{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Live site: http://ec2-54-71-170-71.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

Comment: What are some browsers that don't work?

Comment: The video plays fine on my machine.

Comment: That's the problem, somes peoples says that is not loading and others says that ok. But, in Chrome, they say that is not working...

Comment: Could it be a [compatability issue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility)?

Answer (score 1):

For HTML5 video, you will want to create three formats of the video: webm, mp4, and ogg. Most browsers will use the MP4 but other browsers will require one of the other formats (this would explain why it doesn't work for some users).

```
<video>
    <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

It also should be noted that the order of these formats is important; always declare the webm format first in the list (primarily a Chrome issue).

Finally, the codecs used in the formatting of the videos can play a role in the browser compatibility. I've successfully used the app [Miro Video Converter](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/) to do my conversions and it seems to have the correct codecs available.

Answer (score 1):

Reffer to [Media formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats) to understand which browser support media format. 
You can specify multiple source files. Reference from [HTML5Rocks](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/)
The source element lets you specify multiple formats as a fallback in case the user's browser doesn't support one of them. 
Example:

```
<video controls>
   <source src="devstories.webm" type='video/webm;codecs="vp8, vorbis"'/>
   <source src="devstories.mp4" type='video/mp4;codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
</video>
```